# Why does my toString method return 0?

Tags: java, random, tostring

Why does my `toString` method return 0? I have to concatenate an randomly generated integer onto a String and when I print the result it is always 0. What should I do?

class Cozi:

```
public String toString(){
    String concat="";
    Clienti ob = new Clienti();
    for(int i=1;i <= Clienti.getNrClienti();i++){
        concat = " <" + ob.getRandomInt2() + ">";
        System.out.print(concat);
    }       
    return concat;
}
```

class Clienti:

```
public int serviceTime(){
    System.out.print("\n");
    Random randomServ = new Random();
    for (int idx = 1; idx <= nrClienti; ++idx){
        randomInt2 = randomServ.nextInt(maxServ);
        System.out.println("Generated : " + randomInt2);
    }
    return randomInt2;  
}
```

I have also the methods get and set randomInt2.

I foud out why I was getting only 0. Because randomInt2 was declared int in class Clienti, instead of private static int. Now the problem I got is that my concat object gets only the last value for randomInt2. Any suggestions?

Comment: You haven't provided enough detail here. Please provide a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem. Note that you're not using the previous values of `concat` in your loop, which means you'll only get a single `<some-value>` string out, no matter how many loop iterations you have...

Comment: how can I take the previous values? The thing is:I have this class <<Cozi>> in which I have to have a method to concatenate the Service Time from <<Clienti>>

Comment: Well it would be worth using `StringBuilder`, but until we can see a complete example, it's much harder to help you.

Comment: Remember that overriding `toString()` you have to comply with its contract, which is to give a concise string representation of your current object. You don't seem to be displaying *anything* about your current object. And what does `Clienti.getNrClienti()` do?

Comment: Please do not write code in comments. Take all that information, click on the edit button below your question, and add it to the question, properly formatted.

Comment: I was trying to edit the post but I couldn't becuse it is to much code

Answer (score 2):

If you have an empty String `""` as a return value, then it means you do not enter the `for` loop. Check if the condition `i <= Clienti.getNrClienti()` is met for any `i`.

And there is a bug in the `for` loop, you have to modify:

```
    concat=" <"+ob.getRandomInt2()+">";
```

By

```
    concat += " <"+ob.getRandomInt2()+">";
```

Note: when you want to concatenate `String`s you can use [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) which is more performant.

Comment: But I have to give concat a initial value

Comment: You give the initial value when you declare `String concat = ""`.

Comment: yes, but you were saying that by doing " " this I don't get to enter in the loop.

Comment: You misunderstood (or I was not clear): My saying is, _if_ you just obtain `""` as a return value,  _then_ the program has not entered the `for` loop, because, even if you don't concatenate during the different iterations (as explained in my answer), you still set `concat` to something which is not `""`.  That's just a deduction.

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "a";
s = "b";
System.out.println(s); // b
```

You want to concat if I got that right:

```
String s = "a";
s = s + "b";
System.out.println(s); // ab
```

Comment: I have to concat numbers, but the numbers are generated random. So i don't know what inital value to give to concat.

Comment: Then just use String s = "";